# I am loging into the following website via splash lua script but can't logg in

Tags: web-scraping, lua, scrapy-splash

I want to log in into the `https://login.starcitygames.com/` website  by using splash integration with lua script. i first check in locallhost for testing them.
when detecting all the form css tags and entering log in credentials i failed to logged in.
The code are here:

```
function main(splash)
        splash:set_custom_headers({
        ["user-agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36",
        })
        local url = splash.args.url    
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(10))

        splash:set_viewport_full()

        local search_input = splash:select('input[type=text]')   
        search_input:send_text("(censored)@gmail.com")
        local search_input = splash:select('input[name=password]')
        search_input:send_text("(censored)")
        assert(splash:wait(5))
        local submit_button = splash:select('button[type=submit]')
        submit_button:click()

        assert(splash:wait(15))

        return {
            html = splash:html(),
            png = splash.png(),
         
        }
      end
```

After when i run it on localhost 'http://0.0.0.0:8050/' then the following results is come and can't logged in .
May be the css tags i use is incorrect or anything .
I am new to splash lua so don't understand it.
the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `local search_input = splash:select('input[type=text]')` with `local search_input = splash:select('input[name=username]')`.

Comment: I give me the above results again